# Is it possible to use the Gensim package for non-English languages in Python?

Tags: python, gensim, similarity

I am comparing an input text with texts in a text file. I use the Gensim package for this. Within that package there are several ways to compare an input string with different strings in a text file: First, by looking at the occurrence of words. Only the frequency of words is considered, and not the semantics. The language of the text is therefore not important in that case. The result, however, is that "How old are you?" and "What is your age?" no resemblance, because those sentences consist of only different words. I want those two sentences to overlap, because they do have the same semantics.

I use [this example](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/core/run_similarity_queries.html) for this. The `corpora` and `similarities` modules of the `gensim` package are used for this. However, the input text and the texts in the database file are in Dutch language, not in English.

I have not been able to find anywhere that you can use a non-English language with these modules, but I have also not read anywhere that you cannot. Can someone tell me if this is possible? And if not, does anyone know a good alternative where that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithms in Gensim are generally not English-specific, as long as texts can be tokenized into words. So: what you're trying is possible, and the algorithms/examples in Gensim are a good starting point.

Did you try any of the code from the tutorial example linked on your text? What were the results? How much training text did you supply?

In general, because the algorithms are *not* language specific and don't start with any prior understanding of any language, everything they know needs to be learned from the patterns in texts *you* provide. So, you''ll want to provide as much training data as possible.

That means most of the interesting algorithms won't learn anything from a tiny toy dataset like:

```py
[
  ['how', 'old', 'are', 'you', '?'],
  ['what', 'is', 'your', 'age', '?'],
]
```

That's because, without any other information, that's essentially the exact same data, in the eyes of the algorithm, as:

```py
[
  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
  ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'E'],
]
```

(Only the `'E'` token repeats, in a different place, so at the level of analysis based on co-occurrences, it's the only one different from any others.)

However, if you instead had hundreds, or thousands, or tens-of-thousands of realistic texts from your target language and problem domain, then the algorithm wouldn't be stuck with a single stunted example of token `'B'` (aka, `'old'`). It'd have dozens or hundreds of usage examples, each with a variey of different surrounding words.

At that point, the math in these algorithms *can* detect useful patterns. It'd be likely to then "realize" that `'B'` (`'old'`) and `'I'` (`'age'`) have some relation. In fact, many of these algorithms can detect that even if they never exactly co-occur or replace each other, but just have *other* words they often appear with. At that point, *after* training on a larger corpus, your two sentences might be recognized as being similar.

So:

- don't worry about the Dutch vs English angle, as long as you can segment your text into lists-of-word-tokens well
- do try the examples in the Gensim documentation, but with as much relevant training data as you can practically find or wait for it to train on - that's how it knows words/languages, not from any pre-programmed definitions
- if you hit problems, ensure your questions here describe what you've tried (ideally with actual code) and why the results/errors don't match expectations

Another technique that's relevant is the use of *word-vectors*, which can be trained, or loaded from somebody else's pre-trained vectors, then used to assiste next-steps in performing text analysis. Gensim doesn't come with any word-vectors, but it can be used to train them or load other sets.

The simplest possible way to apply word-vectors to your task might be:

- find someone else's Dutch word-vectors (or train them yourself - which if you have a lot of good domain-specific text may be far bettr than someone else's generic vectors)
- change any multi-word text into the average of all its individual words
- compare those vectors as a basic check of text similarity

This will still miss (or dilute/cancel-out/etc) lots of the human-perceived meaning of a text, because it doesn't consider grammar/word-order/context/etc. But for broad topical comparisons/retrieval, it's a fair baseline.

Any good word-vectors you train or find will likely capture within themselves that `'how'` and `'what'` are question-words, and that `'old'` and `'age'` concern similar lifespan-durations. So this simple baseline will probably indicate your 2 sentences are a bit closer-to-each-other than other random sets of 4-5 words.

Depending on your ultimate need & resources, there are then other more-sophisticated text-modelling or text-comparison things that could be tried - including things which also use word-vectors as input or which feed ordered sequences of words into deeper-neural-network algorithms to create more order/grammar sensitive vector-representations of long texts.